# There were headers present in the request which were not signed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

[AWS Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAgyx.jpg) We are submiting PUT request in Amazon Web Service. But unfortunetly we are getting following error.

> AccessDenied There were headers present in the request which were not
>   signed x-amz-acl, x-amz-server-side-encryption, x-amz-copy-source

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Note: We are using Amazon Singature Version 4.

Comment: Check your bucket policy or update your bucket policy. I am posting some additional references FYI . Go through it if not works reply  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html#WebsiteRestEndpointDiff , http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with your bucket policy.

Comment: How are you generating the signature?  What code is being used?

Comment: Michael, thanks. We fixed the issue last night.

Comment: We had not added x-amz-* headers as "SignedHeaders" in "Authorization"

Comment: @AnilMeghnathi can you add that peice of code here for my reference ? thanks

Comment: @AnilMeghnathi  awesome that you fixed the issue...  would be great to share that as well...