# active storage direct upload issue with s3 encryption

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, rails-activestorage, pre-signed-url

I've been trying to get active storage working with direct uploads in my react project.
Keep getting a 403 because of the 'Deny' in my IAM policy.

I have active storage setup with the following storage.yml file

```
production:
  service: S3
  bucket: <bucketname>
  region: "us-east-1"
  access_key_id: <access_key>
  secret_access_key: <secret_access_key>
  upload:
    server_side_encryption: "AES256"
```

I am using the direct upload mentioned [here](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads) in the rails docs using this [package](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/package/@rails/activestorage)

The IAM policy looks like this

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My bucket's CORS settings

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*",
            "x-amz-server-side-encryption"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://localhost:8000/",
            "http://localhost:8000",
            "http://localhost:8010/"
        ]
    }
]
```

I've tried every suggestion I can find on google and finally tracked down the issue.

If I remove

```
{
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
                }
            }
        }
```

from the IAM policy, **it works!**

But I want the extra security.

My presigned URL I am getting from the `rails/active_storage/direct_uploads` endpoint looks like this.

https://.s3.amazonaws.com/1fhy070cp9l4oegb3mcq5mta0rgx?x-amz-server-side-encryption=AES256&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=...

EDIT: here's the FE code that does the uploading via the rails/activestorage package

```html
const getLogoBlob = (logo: File, callback: (blob: Blob) => void) => {
  const upload = new DirectUpload(
    logo,
    `${env.baseUrl}/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads`,
  );
  upload.create(async (error, blob) => {
    if (error) {
      throw new Error('Failed to upload logo');
    }

    callback(blob);
  });
};
```

Comment: x-amz-server-side-encryption is supposed to be a http request header. I don't know if it will be honored as part of the url query string.

Comment: Did you add `x-amz-server-side-encryption` to the URL when generating the pre-signed URL? Or did you just add it _after_ generating the pre-signed URL?

Comment: @Schwern I have tried to upload something to the presigned_url in postman by making a put requests to it and adding x-amz-server-side-encryption as a header, it returns "Access Denied There were headers present in the request which were not signed".

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It's in the presigned_url that's received from the rails/active_storage/direct_uploads endpoint.

Comment: Still stuck on this, any pointers would be appreciated. :)

Comment: @dbugger works but removing that allows all files in, but I need to block everything else except AES256.

Comment: @MoonLight Can we see your Postman? Does [the solution in the comments to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653850/there-were-headers-present-in-the-request-which-were-not-signed#comment78272432_45653850) help? Or [this issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/discussions/2810) or [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/955377/updated-aws-sdk-and-now-getting-presigned-errors)?

Comment: @Schwern I am actually testing this in my app's implementation, I can provide that code. I'll add it in the main post. I have already been over all the links you've posted. None worked. :(

Comment: @MoonLight Do you have the `aws-sdk-s3` gem in your Gemfile? See [the Rails Guide on ActiveStorage and S3](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#s3-service-amazon-s3-and-s3-compatible-apis)

Comment: @Schwern fixed the edit added the right code that does the uploading/connecting to backend.
The react app is separate which connects to the rails api so I've used this yarn package https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/package/@rails/activestorage
Yes, I do have the aws-sdk-s3 gem.

Comment: Main issue is with the IAM policy. Removing 
"s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
works but I need the security.